# How to get position (X,Y) of any visual node after page rendered?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I need to create a draggable button. The drag starts from multiple source and ends at a sink. Is there any way to get position of the sources and the sink after creation of the page.

```js
Container {
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                Label {
                    id: preId
                    preferredWidth: 700

                    text: rootContainer.data.part1
                    multiline: true
                    textStyle {
                        textAlign: TextAlign.Center
                        color: Color.Black
                    }
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                }
            }
            Container {
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

                SinkButton {
                    id: sinkId
                    preferredHeight: 100
                    preferredWidth: 686
                    textColor: Color.Black
                    enabled: false
                    layoutProperties: AbsoluteLayoutProperties {

                    }
                }
            }
            Container {
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
                topPadding: -5
                bottomPadding: squareDisplay ? 10 : 50
                Label {
                    id: postId
                    text: rootContainer.data.postData
                    multiline: true
                    textStyle {
                        textAlign: TextAlign.Center
                        color: Color.Black
                    }
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to know the position of "sinkId" relative to the window. Its position varies depending on "preId" text length. `LayoutUpdateHandler` is a possible solution but `layoutFrame.x` or `layoutFrame.y` always comes zero on checking. Is there any way to get position of any visual node on/after page creation?

Comment: what is `SinkButton` in you code? I guess it's a custom widget. You need to provide the code for this as well otherwise that piece of code won't have a chance to be launched

Answer (score 1):

First, `LayoutUpdateHandler` reports `layoutFrame` properties quite well, not sure why it's not working in your case. Here is the working code demonstrating that if you want to utilise this class for your needs:

```js
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {}
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
        Button {
            id: button
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            text: "click me"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("Button layout - x:" + layoutHandler.layoutFrame.x + ", y:" + layoutHandler.layoutFrame.y + 
                            ", width:"+ layoutHandler.layoutFrame.width + ", height: " + layoutHandler.layoutFrame.height);
            }

            attachedObjects: [
                LayoutUpdateHandler {
                    id: layoutHandler
                }
            ] 
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to respond to touch events of your widget which I guess draggable functionality means, the best bet here would be to use a series of touch-input reactions provided by `touchBehaviors` which could added to any `VisualNode` as via QML as via C++, doesn't matter. So in order to do this, you need to create a `TouchBehavior` object with a defined `TouchReaction` with respective properties.

So, for example, for tracking touch events of some `VisualNode` upon receiving a touch down event until a touch up one occurs you need to define a respective `touchBehaviour` object and connect to the `onTouch()` slot of that `VisualNode` where you get all the events captured by your `touchBehaviour` event filter. Here is the code demonstrating this approach:

```js
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {}
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
        Button {
            id: button
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            text: "click me"

            touchBehaviors: [
                TouchBehavior {
                    TouchReaction {
                        eventType: TouchType.Down
                        phase: PropagationPhase.AtTarget
                        response: TouchResponse.StartTracking
                    }
                }
            ]

            onTouch: {
                console.log("===== got touch event of type " + event.touchType + " =====");
                console.log("\twindowX - " + event.windowX);
                console.log("\twindowX - " + event.windowX);
                console.log("\twindowY - " + event.windowY);
                console.log("\tlocalX - " + event.localX);
                console.log("\tlocalY - " + event.localY);
                console.log("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add you logic in `onTouch()` slot handler.

Additional information on the subject:

- [TouchBehavior official documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__touchbehavior.html)
- [TouchEvent official documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__touchevent.html)
- [VisualNode touch event function official documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__visualnode.html#function-touch-event)

Answer (score 0):

LayoutUpdateHandler will tell you the position of your element in relation to the parent, which in the case of SinkId is a Container wrapping it. LayoutUpdateHandler will always return you 0 in this case.

Either remove the container and set the horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center property on sinkId directly and use a LayoutUpdateHandler, or use a LayoutUpdateHandler on the container surrounding sinkId.